# Sub Grids not working in meteor

Tags: jquery, meteor

I want to use JQuery Subgrid with Meteor. But when I use their code in Meteor it does not work. Without meteor it works. This is my code as shown in screen shot in meteor it never showing any result.

[Click here to view Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2bHW.png)

[Grid Demo](http://sw-amt.ws/w2ui/demos/#!grid/grid-7)

Comment: This way you will never get an answer. Expert here on SO help on the basis of what you have done till now. You are asking for someone to cook code for you. This should not be the approach. Kindly show use the code where have you reached so far. We can definitely help.

Comment: Yes Sir ! I have veen edited my Question

Answer (score 0):

Considering the code you provided. You must write the Jquery or Javascript code inside `Template.YourTemplateName.js` file. Below is the proper way to write the code inside `onRendered` function which is specially designed to meet after-effects when template is rendered.

For more information on how many such methods are available

1. [Link 1](https://forums.meteor.com/t/about-oncreated-onrendered-ondestroyed-and-helpers/165)
2. [Link 2](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered)

You must try below peice of code and make sure the supportive w2-grid js and css files are properly imported.

**Template.YourTemplateName.js**

```
Template.YourTemplateName.onRendered(function(){
    $('#grid').w2grid9({.....});
});
```

Comment: Your import for gris js and CSS is not working I guess. Where have you imported them?

Comment: I save both files on Meteor

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with version of W2ui.js file .I was using w2ui1.4.3.js and its not worked but when I use w2ui-1.5.rc1.min.js then it start work in Meteor.
but still append event not working